# Coded UI test - Can't load CodedUITestFramework when using app.config

Tags: app-config, coded-ui-tests

I have a CodedUI project (Visual Studio 2015 Update 3) that I have been using successfully to test my application. An issue arose where I wanted to add more logging, so I created an App.Config for the project with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
   <system.diagnostics>
     <switches>
       <add name="EqtTraceLevel" value="4" />
     </switches>
   </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

When I attempt to run the same tests that worked previous to adding the App.Config file, I receive the following error:

> Result Message:
>   Unit Test Adapter threw exception: 
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..

Any thoughts on why simply adding this file would cause the issue? I have also tried creating a completely new solution/project with a simple test and adding the app.config file with the same result. I have been able to do this successfully in the past so not sure why I can't this time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check in bin folder  for the associated XML.after clean up and rebuild check in bin folder .it should be present in bin .this error due to its not able to find file in bin folder of your solution